# Consolas font too thin

Tags: fonts, text-editors

When I use my other computer the consolas font is appearing way thinner than it used to be. Here are 2 images to show the differences: [Font Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqLiH.png) and [Font Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouVY1.png) I tried changing the fontWeight and size in my text editors but it still look different. (It tried different text editors and the font is different for all of them)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The images are at different magnifications, so it's hard to directly compare.  But eyeballing it, they look like pretty similar proportions.